# Last Thanksgiving

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, this-next, this-last

Would "last Thanksgiving" at the end of 2014 refer to November 27, 2014 or November 27, 2013? Technically, the most recent Thanksgiving would be the former but the Thanksgiving in the last year would be the latter. What about in January of 2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a context where particular precision might be expected, "last Thanksgiving" would be taken to mean Thanksgiving 2014 from the next day on.

Generally though, it would still be taken as referring to 2013 on that date.

There is no clear rule about when "last X" changes from meaning "the X before the current one" and "the current X" replaces it as the "last X".

Around now, it would be rather ambiguous; it's over a month ago on the one hand (encouraging us to consider 2014 as "last Thanksgiving") but it's in the same year and indeed the same holiday season as that on the other hand (encouraging us to consider 2013 as "last Thanksgiving").

There's also a big mental difference between someone whose social activity has been very much concentrated very much first on Thanksgiving and then on the build up to Christmas followed by Christmas itself, for whom "this Thanksgiving" is still much of a concept, compared to someone who last November noticed "oh, the Americans are doing that thing were they eat turkey a month too early" and thought little more of it.

The first such person might well consider November 28, 2013 as "last Thanksgiving" and the latter would consider "wasn't it some time in November?" as "last Thanksgiving".

Comment: You explain it so well; the headache that I have had since I woke up this morning has vanished!

Comment: Though, I'm afraid you don't really know when last Thanksgiving was. English is not always good at precision unless the speaker takes pains for it to be so.

Answer (score 0):

In December, it could easily refer to either. (Except Thanksgiving was not on November 27 in 2013 :)

If you say *last Thanksgiving* to refer to your most recent Thanksgiving, some people might **misinterpret** your intentions. Your listener must make a difficult choice:

Does *last* refer to:

> your *last* experience of Thanksgiving?
>
> or
>
> *last* year's Thanksgiving?

If you say *this Thanksgiving* to refer to your most recent Thanksgiving, **very few** people would be confused--especially if you are referring to just a month ago. If there is a choice of referents, *this* is **more likely** to mean *the one that is closer*.

In January of 2015, **fewer** people would misinterpret your intentions in the phrase "last Thanksgiving".

The issue is establishing an obvious frame of reference that you and your listener can agree on.

Comment: Obviously. That's why I asked the question. If I didn't know that, I wouldn't ask. This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Take a look at it with the explanations reversed.

Comment: Okay, let's put it this way. It's January 2015. When I say "last Thanksgiving," what does it more likely mean? I realize there's ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I see it differently...

(A week before Thanksgiving, 2014...)

"Did Aunt Betty make the string bean casserole last Thanksgiving?" (2013)

(On Thanksgiving, 2014...)

"Last Thanksgiving we had the *good* cranberry sauce with the can marks." (2013)

(Until the end of 2014...)

*This past*(2014) Thanksgiving there was snow on the ground, but last Thanksgiving (2013) it was fifty degrees outside.

I wouldn't think of 2014 as *last* Thanksgiving until after the holiday season.
Until then, *this past* would make your meaning clearer.